# How do I show navbar items based on a model field in Django?

Tags: python, django, if-statement

I have a `Blog` model that looks like this:

```
class Blog(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blogs')
    parent = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=PARENT_TUTORIALS)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog_list", args=[str(self.parent), str(self.slug)])
```

I can succesfully display all the blogs on a table of contents via my `table.html` template:

```
{% for blog in blog_list %}
    <li><a href="{{ blog.get_absolute_url }}">{{blog.title}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

However, I want to show only those blogs that have the same `Blog.parent` value as the current blog page. For example, the page `example.com/biology/page1`, has `biology` as a parent. When the user is on that page, the table of contents should show only the pages that have `biology` as a parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add an if statement like so?

**template.html**

```html
{% for blog in blog_list %}
  {% if blog.parent == current_blog.parent %}
    <li><a href="{{ blog.get_absolute_url }}">{{blog.title}}</a></li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Another option is to filter with js, something like (untested):

**template.html**

```html
{% for blog in blog_list %}
  <li class="blog-list-item {{blog.parent}}">
    <a href="{{ blog.get_absolute_url }}">{{blog.title}}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

**script.js**

```js
$('.blog-list-item').filter(':not(.biology)').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks! But, where does `current_blog` come from?

Comment: Probably you meant I can hardcode it as in `blog.parent == 'biology'`, but I have many parent values, not only `biology`.

Comment: Solved it! I did `{% if blog.parent == view.kwargs.parent %}`. Thanks again - very helpful!

Comment: `current_blog` was assumed to be a context variable - I guess it wasn't - but seems you were able to get the data you needed anyway